# Detect infrastructure provider in a custom controller

Tags: kubernetes

Is there a way to detect infrastructure provider (e.g., GKE, AKS, On-Prem) in a Kubernetes custom controller? I need to check and configure things differently as different environments have different constraints.

Comment: Maybe you can fetch `Node.Spec.ProviderID` value per each K8s node, propagated  by a specific provider's cloud node controller.

Comment: Thanks! That seems to be the best we can rely on.

Answer (score 1):

Recently I have been also interested in the same task. So far, I've deserved K8s provider detection through catching particular `ProviderID` field, promoted by a specific cloud provider's [*Controller Manager*](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/running-cloud-controller/), on each k8s target node.

```
kubectl get no | awk '{print $1}'| sed '1d'| while read -r node; do echo "$node=$(kubectl get no $node -o jsonpath='{.spec.providerID}')"; done
```

Sharing your experience and further progress with more efficient solution will be highly appreciated.

Hope that this can be useful also for any other community contributors research.